# python naive bayes classifier error

Tags: python, classification

I'm trying to build a naive bayes classifier which read data from a text file and outputs to a text file and my code is gettin an error sayin the the return is outside of the function however i can see no error

```
# compute the relative frequencies of the
# 2nd explanatory variable taking on the
# values 'A', 'B' and 'C'
# and return a dictionary with these values
def getCatProbs(self, data):
  a_count = 0
  b_count = 0
  c_count = 0
  probs = {}
for row in data:
  if row[1] == ">50K":
     a_count = a_count + 1
  if row[1] == "<=50K":
     b_count = b_count + 1
  else:
     c_count = c_count + 1

     probs[">50K"] = float(a_count)/len(data)
     probs["<=50K"] = float(b_count)/len(data)
     probs['C'] = float(c_count)/len(data)

  return probs
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, indentation matters. For example in your code definition of function `getCatProbs` is finished after line `probs = {}`, which clearly leaves the `return` outside the funciton body.

Here is how this code might look like with proper indents:

```
# compute the relative frequencies of the
# 2nd explanatory variable taking on the
# values 'A', 'B' and 'C'
# and return a dictionary with these values
def getCatProbs(self, data):
    a_count = 0
    b_count = 0
    c_count = 0
    probs = {}
    for row in data:
        if row[1] == ">50K":
            a_count = a_count + 1
        if row[1] == "<=50K":
            b_count = b_count + 1
        else:
            c_count = c_count + 1

    probs[">50K"] = float(a_count)/len(data)
    probs["<=50K"] = float(b_count)/len(data)
    probs['C'] = float(c_count)/len(data)

    return probs
```

Comment: doin that returns and error saying it does not match any outer indentation level :/

Comment: @user2311700, it might be if your are using tabs for indentation instead of spaces. Try substituting every 4 spaces above with 1 tab.

Answer (score 1):

Your return is indeed outside of your function.  The entire `for` loop is outside of your function.  I think you meant to indent the `for` loop one more level so it's inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Format is meaningful in Python.

It looks to me like you're not consistent in your indentation.  The for loop and subsequent lines appear to be off.

I'd recommend using a good IDE.  JetBrains makes the best ones on the market.  Try [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).  It'll make it more difficult to make such mistakes.